# Get component variable value of a public variable not visible in the dom

Tags: angular, cypress

I have an Angular component I am testing.  I am trying see how the components public variable value changes given different interaction with the DOM.

The component itself is very complicated But I have a stripped down example

```js
export class AgePricingComponent{
   pricing = new Pricing();

   onClick() {
      pricing.amount = 5;
   }
}
```

In my test I want to test that pricing.amount = 5;
so I use the following test:

```js
  it('should set all of the age pricing', () => {
    cy.get('#age-amount-0').clear().type(-5);
    cy.get('#submit-btn').click(); 
    cy.window().then((win)=>{
      let pricing = win.pricing.amount;
      cy.log(pricing); expect(pricing.amount).equals(-5);

    })
  });
```

The error I get is

> TypeError: **win.pricing is undefined**
> at ./cypress/e2e/admin/create-new-tournament.cy.js/</ (webpack:///./cypress/e2e/admin/create-new-tournament.cy.js:40:20)
> at getRet (http://localhost:4200/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:139235:20)
> From previous event:
> ...

How can I check that value of my public pricing property?

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't automatically add variables to `window`, in fact it tries to hide them to avoid polluting the global object.

You would need to explicitly add it yourself, if `window.Cypress` is present indicating the app is being tested.

```js
export class AgePricingComponent{

   pricing = new Pricing();

   // only when Cypress is running
   if (window.Cypress) {
    window.pricing = pricing
  }

   onClick() {
      pricing.amount = 5;
   }
}
```

If you inject the Pricing class, you could also mock it during the test.